# Is VirtualHost a good pattern in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, virtualhost

I have 100 clients. Each client has unique username, password and two channels (users can't connect to different channels apart from their own). Should I create VirtualHost for each user?

How to write proper user permission to the below situation?:

- `my_user` can connect only to vahost called `user_vhost` using `username` and `password`
- `my_user` can consume only from the `user_channel` channel
- `my_user` can publish only to the `user_channel` channel
- `my_user` can connect remotely

Thank You!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Virutal host in RabbitMQ is more like a logical container where a user connected to a particular virtual host cannot access any resource (exchange, queue...) from another virtual host. I always think about it like a administrative domain kind of thing.

Based on what you have explained, I think having a virtual host per user is a good way to keep things simple and clean. Also, this way you do not need to come up with complicated permissions rules, just grant permissions based on virtual host.

Comment: How about creating, deleting, declaring queues, exchanges etc? Consumer should not have access to this action. Can I achieve this using only granting permission per vhost?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to set that kind of permissions using, for example, `rabbitmqctl`

Comment: How to do it? :-) I'm searching examples several hours :-)

Comment: Well, you can use something like this `rabbitmqctl set_permissions your_user "^$"
"^$" "your_user_.*"` . If I am not wrong, this will grant permission to your_user for reading resources that start with the name "your_user_". The regexp `^$` is for denying.

Comment: To give read access to the queue `myqueue` I used: `rabbitmqctl set_permissions my_user "myqueue.*" "^$" "myqueue.*"` .. it works, but user can delete the queue, purge the queue etc. How to prevent it? I found default perms on http://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html, but I doesn't work, eg. `rabbitmqctl set_permissions my_user "myqueue.*" "^$" "$(myqueue.queue.declare|myqueue.basic.consume)$"`. I've got "403, ACCESS_REFUSED - access to queue 'myqueue' in vhost '.' refused for user 'my_user'". :-(

Comment: Here's the documentation for permissions https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html